# Were military-grade P-38 and P-51 can openers supposed to last a lifetime?

Tags: military

Were military-grade [P-38 and P-51](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-38_can_opener) can openers supposed to last a lifetime?

Wikipedia says:

> The original U.S.-contract P-38 can openers were manufactured by J.W.
> Speaker Corporation of Germantown, Wisconsin (stamped "US Speaker")
> and by Washburn Corporation (marked "US Androck"); they were later
> made by Mallin Shelby Hardware inc (defunct 1973) of Shelby, Ohio and
> were variously stamped "US Mallin Shelby O." or "U.S. Shelby Co."

It's easy to find P-38/P-51 stamped "U.S. Shelby Co." sold online and I have bought some from several military surplus sellers, all of them claimed that the can openers were real military surplus. However none of them lasted more than a year or two, i.e. a few hundreds of cans (after a while the tab that hooks under the can lip wears out, rendering it no longer functional.)

I have read multiple testimonies from U.S. military veterans who claimed that the original military-grade can openers would last through decades of use.

For example:

> [Not hardened metal like the originals](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R37A17QR2U545R/)
>
> I'm a former U.S. Marine rifleman who ate C-rations and used the "John
> Wayne" P-38 can openers for 4 years on active duty. I still have my
> original John Wayne from boot camp in 1972, and the metal is still in
> excellent condition.
>
> But just after only one use of these new Shelbys, the hook that
> engages the rim of the can is deformed so that it is no longer sharp.
> I've tried several other new Shelbys with the same results, so I'm
> convinced it's not an isolated case. This never happened with the
> originals after years of use, almost on a daily basis. Mind you, the
> cutting blade that swings out is just fine. I think they hardened only
> the cutting blade to save money on the new Shelbys.
>
> The problem with that is that the opener does not grip the can's rim
> very well, and it takes some effort (much more than with the
> originals) to move the opener around the can while it cuts. It becomes
> an aggravating chore just to open a single can.
>
> Note to Shelby: Harden the entire opener, not just the blade, and
> charge more if you want. It's not worth two cents the way it is now.

The one on the Wikipedia page seems to be an original piece:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something? What led you to believe that they would last a lifetime?

Comment: I have read such comments from Vietnam War veterans who compared the ones they had bought from those military surplus sellers, to a real military can opener they kept from their military service. The latter has still been functioning throughout all those years.

Comment: Thanks.  Could you add that to the question for clarity?

Comment: Is it just me or is it kind of a big stretch to call this a question about history?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Updated.

Comment: If they were built to last a lifetime, that would be a terrible waste of war material. They're disposable items. Perhaps the originals were over-engineered and they found efficiencies, like not hardening the whole thing.

Comment: The Wikipedia page that you linked to explains (in the very first paragrahp): *was issued in the canned field rations of the United States Armed Forces from World War II to the 1980s. Originally designed for and distributed in the K-ration, it was later included in the C-ration.* If you include those items in each ration you serve, you do not design them to last. One probable issue is that servicemen where used to using brand new openers each time, and never had to deal with one that had an extended service life.

Comment: And from the last quotation, the nostalgic veteran that loved them so much in 1972 must probably be close to 70 years old these days. Maybe there are other factors in play related to how now it is harder for him to open cans with the same tool that was so satisfactory 50 years ago: physical decay, idealized memories... Perhaps even the cans themselves are not completely the same.

Comment: @SJuan76 I doubt the Vietnam War era U.S. can openers were so short-lived as the new ones. In history one has to start from the evidence, not from the conclusion. It was one example I quoted, out of many I have read, all claiming that their service time's can openers have been functioning for decades. The thing is that you can't really be nostalgic here. A worn out hook is very visible, and objectively makes the tool barely functional. There's also the question of why they come with a chain hole if they are so disposable.

Comment: BTW I don't think more durable metal is so expensive for an established well-funded military like the U.S. military. It is a consideration for manufacturers of cheap knockoffs, that make a living out of every penny they could save. It's almost certain that those stamped "U.S. Shelby Co." which are sold nowadays online en masse, are not real military production as "Mallin Shelby Hardware inc" has been defunct for decades.

Comment: @BrianZ I can easily envision history PhD students write doctoral theses on this subject. https://coolmaterial.com/home/tools/p-38-can-opener-history/ https://www.army.mil/article/25736/the_best_army_invention_ever

Answer (score 4):

Have a close look at this can opener:
[image: ep 38 can opener]

Does this look it is made to last for years?

We used similar openers when I served in the army. They came with each ration package. Supposing they were designed to last a lifetime, we would have been issued one each per person.

Comment: What era are you referring to?